# is there a native php function to see if one array of values is in another array?

Tags: php

Is there a better method than loop with strpos()?

Not i'm looking for partial matches and not an in_array() type method.

example needle and haystack and desired return:

```
$needles[0] = 'naan bread';
$needles[1] = 'cheesestrings';
$needles[2] = 'risotto';
$needles[3] = 'cake';

$haystack[0] = 'bread';
$haystack[1] = 'wine';
$haystack[2] = 'soup';
$haystack[3] = 'cheese';

//desired output - but what's the best method of getting this array?
$matches[0] = 'bread';
$matches[1] = 'cheese';
```

ie:

magic_function($haystack, %$needles%) !

Comment: [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: Nope,  won't compare `bread` against `naan bread`. The OP seems to be looking for a wildcard matching function.

Comment: will this work for non-exact matches?

Comment: Dohh - missed that `naan`. Than he should explode all elements with space delimiter but that all is not then a native function at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing `$haystack` and `$needle` in your question, because *naan bread* is not in haystack, nor is *cheesestring*. Your desired output suggests you are looking for *cheese* in *cheesestring* instead. For that, the following would work:

```
function in_array_multi($haystack, $needles)
{
    $matches = array();
    $haystack = implode('|', $haystack);
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== FALSE) {
            $matches[] = $needle;
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}
```

For your given haystack and needles this performs twice as fast as a regex solution. Might change for different number of params though.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($haystack as $pattern) {
    if (preg_grep('/'.$pattern.'/', $needles)) {
        $matches[] = $pattern;
    }
}
```

Comment: function magic_function($haystack, $needles) {
    // code above here :)
}

Comment: returns an array with four elements: bread, cheese, bread, cheese

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to roll your own. The User Contributed Comments to [array_intersect()](http://en.php.net/array_intersect) provide a number of alternative implementations (like [this one](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php#95419)). You would just have to replace the `==` matching against `strstr()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data[0] = 'naan bread';
$data[1] = 'cheesestrings';
$data[2] = 'risotto';
$data[3] = 'cake';

$search[0] = 'bread';
$search[1] = 'wine';
$search[2] = 'soup';
$search[3] = 'cheese';

preg_match_all(
    '~' . implode('|', $search) . '~',
    implode("\x00", $data),
    $matches
);

print_r($matches[0]); 

// [0] => bread
// [1] => cheese
```

You'll get better answers if you tell us more about the *real* problem.